# Saving csv file with multer and fs

Tags: node.js, fs, multer

I'm working on node.js server and want to save a csv file that's passed through multer on file system. Saving process works fine without throwing error, meta data seems to be saved correctly, but contents are not written.
When opening the created csv file, there's only "[object Undefined]" saying.

Here's code.

```
const buf = Buffer.from(toString(uploadedCsv));
fs.writeFileSync(basePath + uploadedCsv.originalname, buf);
```

Here's saved data.

```
[object Undefined]
```

I want an output like this.

```
"0", "1", "US"
"1", "1", "JP"
```

How can I save the contents properly?

Thanks.

Comment: `console.log(buf)` before writing the file, what does it log?

Comment: @GrafiCode console.log(buf) : <Buffer 5b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 55 6e 64 65 66 69 6e 65 64 5d>  and console.log(uploadedCsv) : { fieldname: 'uploadedCsv',
  originalname: 'info.csv',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'text/csv',
  buffer: <Buffer ef bb bf 22 30 30 31 22 2c 22 22 2c 22 e6 9c ac e7 a4 be 22 2c 22 30 30 31 22 2c 22 31 22 2c 22 30 22 0a 22 30 30 32 22 2c 22 30 30 31 22 2c 22 e7 ae ... >,
  size: 453 }

Comment: `const buf = Buffer.from(toString(uploadedCsv.buffer));` this should only bufferize `uploadedCsv.buffer`

Comment: @GrafiCode I tried `const buf = Buffer.from(toString(uploadedCsv.buffer));` BUT the result was still the same "[object Undefined]" ;(

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking, should you decode your buffer before writing it to file?

Comment: like `buffer.toString('utf-8')`?

Comment: Worked with `Buffer.from(uploadedCsv.buffer.toString('utf-8'))` !! Thank you very much!! But I have another question now.  This time we only write the contents to the file and the meta data, such as originalname or mimetype, is gone away?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain your last question?

Comment: It seems that I misunderstood something... I thought when we save uploadedCsv to our file system, meta info, such as originalname, mimetype or size, is also saved as well as the actual contents and we can access the meta info with "Properties" or something.